# Calculating variance for a sequence of i.i.d. variables which seems non-partitionable

Tags: probability

> Let $(Z_n : 1 \leq n < \infty )$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables with $$\mathbb{P}(Z_n=0)=q=1-p,\quad \mathbb{P}(Z_n=1)=p.$$ Let $A_i$ be the event $$\{Z_i=0\}\cap\{Z_{i-1}=1\}.$$  If $U_n$ is the number of times $A_i$ occurs for $2 \leq i \leq n$, prove $\mathbb{E}(U_n)=(n-1)pq$, and find the variance of $U_n$.

I was able to solve this question, only calculating the variance didn't work. I think it's best to use $$\mathrm{Var}(U_n)=\mathbb{E}(U_n^2)-\mathbb{E}(U_n)^2,$$ because the second expectation is already calculated. However, I have no idea how to calculate $\mathbb{E}(U_n^2)$. Can anyone provide some help?

EDIT:

By the way, the variance should be $\mathrm{Var}(U_n)=(n-1)pq-(3n-5)(pq)^2$, so the second moment of $U_n$ should be $(n-1)pq+(n-3)(n-2)(pq)^2$. Still, I have no clue how to calculate this second moment.

EDIT 2:

Using Dean's answer, I tried solving for the variance. We have a random sum for the amount of zeros in $\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$, which has a binomial distribution with parameters $n-1$ and $q$. Then we obtain in total $j$ zero's, which can be preceded by ones. The preceding elements follow a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$. Thus, we can set up the probability generating functions to obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
G_{zero's}(s) & = & (p+qs)^{n-1}\\
G_{ones}(s) & = &q+ps\\
G_{U_n}(s) & = & G_{zero's}(G_{ones}(s))=(p+q(q+ps))^{n-1}\\
G_{U_n}'(s) & = & (n-1)(p+q(q+ps))^{n-2}pq\\
G_{U_n}''(s) & = & (n-1)(n-2)(p+q(q+ps))^{n-3}(pq)^2\\
\mathrm{Var}(U_n) & = & G_{U_n}''(1)+G_{U_n}'(1)-G_{U_n}'(1)^2\\
& = & (n-1)(n-2)(pq)^2+(n-1)pq-(n-1)^2(pq)^2\\
& = & (n-1)pq+(n-1)(n-2-n+1)(pq)^2\\
& = & (n-1)pq-(n-1)(pq)^2.
\end{eqnarray}
However, the answer for this question says that the variance should be $\mathrm{Var}(U_n)=(n-1)pq-(3n-5)(pq)^2$, and since this is an old Oxford examination question, it seems unlikely that their answer is wrong. Also, the probability generating function seems allright, since $G_{U_n}'(1)$ indeed yields $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Any ideas on where I can have made a mistake? It seems also strange to me that we determine a random sum which can yield at most $n-1$ zero's, and then treat this like every one of these zeros can have a preceding one. For example, when all tosses yield a zero, we know for sure that $U_n=0$, while the above implies that we have $n-1$ Bernoulli trials, so quite likely $U_n\neq 0$. How to fix this?

Comment: How did you find $\mathbb E[U_n]$?

Comment: I used indicator function functions $1_{A_i}$ for all $i \in \{2, 3, \ldots, n\}$. The probability such an indictor function gives a $1$ is equal to $pq$ since this happens iff $Z_i=1 \wedge Z_{i-1}$. If we take the expectation of the sum of these indicator variables, $\mathbb{E}(U_n)=(n-1)pq$ follows from the linearity of the expecations operator, and the fact that $\mathbb{E}(1_{A_i})=\mathbb{P}(A_i=1)=pq$. However, a more direct approach  seems necessary for , $\mathbb{E}(U_n^2)$, because the problem is that the $A_i$'s are clearly not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_i=1$ if $Z_i=1$ and $Z_{i+1}=0$  and $0$ otherwise. Note that $ET_i=pq$ and that $T_i T_{i+1} = 0.$ Then $U_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T_i$ and $$\mathrm{Var}(U_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathrm{Var}(T_i) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \mathrm{Cov}(T_i,T_j)$$
$$ = (n-1)\,\mathrm{Var}(T_1) + 2(n-2)\,\mathrm{Cov}(T_1,T_2),$$
by symmetry and by observing that $\mathrm{Cov}(T_i,T_j) = 0$ if the set $\{i,i+1\}\cap\{j,j+1\}=\phi.$

But  $\mathrm{Var}(T_1)=ET_1^2 - (ET_1)^2= pq(1-pq),$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(T_1,T_2)=E(T_1 T_2)-(pq)^2 = -(pq)^2$ since $T_1T_2=0.$

So $$\mathrm{Var}(U_n) = (n-1)pq(1-pq) - 2(n-2)(pq)^2.$$

Comment: This is really helpful. In my second edit, I incorrectly assumed independence.I can see that I was close, because adding the covariance term $\mathrm{Cov}(U_n)=-(pq)^2(2n-4)$ corrects for dependence and yields the right answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following is an incorrect treatment (incorrectly assuming independence)... just leaving in place for reference.

Let $J$ be the number of zeros in the sequence, not counting the first element. $J$ is binomial with $n-1$ trials and probability q.

For a sample with $j$ zeros beyond the first element, the number that precede the zero with a one is $U$ which is binomial with $j$ trials and probability p.

The pmf for U is therefore given by:
$$f(u) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} B(j|n-1,q)B(u|j,p)$$

From that you can work out the second moment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't think about this yet. I still cannot manage to get the expression for the second moment using this though. When I write it out it doesn't simplify.

Comment: I think this is just the case discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065584/sum-over-product-of-two-binomial-distributions and here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/stochastic-inequality-with-product-of-binomial-distributions... U is Binomial with $n-1$ trials and probability $pq$. This gives a variance that does not agree with your answer though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using what you said in your initial post I worked something out and I have the feeling I'm almost there. I edited my post, will you look at it? The question is from an old Oxford examination so it seems a bit odd that it contains a mistake.

Comment: You are right - the problem is more difficult than I first understood it to be. The $A_i$ are not independent. I edited the answer above to indicate it is incorrect. I have not thought of an easy solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

A correct approach would be to use the "run test", which counts the number of runs in a two-state sequence as a test of the independence of the elements of the sequence. Use the "run test" pmf for the number of runs $R$, given $n$ and $p$. Each time a run of ones end, you have satisfied the condition $A$. The pmf for $U$ is found by considering that $R=U/2$. Alternatively you could use $E[R]$ and $V[R]$ directly to find $E[U]$ and $E[U]$.

Here is one site that explains how to derive the pmf for the run test:
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/233

Comment: But if I understand this right, the run test is just a non-parametric statistical test, testing the independence of two events (or like a mean test). In this case, we already saw the events are dependent so how would this test outcome be of any relevance? I understand that you might try to calculate the expected number of runs and the variance of the number of runs, but isn't Kimchi's approach way more direct then? Besides, in the run test we look how to make sequences of a given amont of 1's and 0's right? In this case we don't know a priori the amount of 1's and 0's

Comment: Yes, Kimchi's approach is the best. His answer came in after my comment. The formulation of the pmf for this problem would be slightly different than the pmf for the run test, in that $p$ would be specified instead of the number of 0's and 1's. I suggested the run test, as this problem reminded me of that test, and the number of runs is related to the number of "10" combinations that appear.

Comment: Okay I see. I thought the run test was more like a hypothesis test so I thought it had nothing to do with calculating the variance.